# backbone and requireJS - where is the dependency

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to understand the Backbone + RequireJS version of the TodoMVC. I don't understand why in the main.js file, the backbone package is not dependency?

```
// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
require.config({
    // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
    // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: [
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            ],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        underscore: '../../../assets/lodash.min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone',
        text: 'lib/require/text'
    }
});

require([
    'views/app',
    'routers/router' // <--views/app.js and routers/router.js are the only dependencies
], function( AppView, Workspace ) {
    // Initialize routing and start Backbone.history()
    new Workspace();
    Backbone.history.start(); // <--Here we use Backbone variable. Where do the writer tell the page about the backbone dependency??

    // Initialize the application view
    new AppView();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone is exported as a global by the shim configuration so it's not necessary to define the dependency because it's already available in the global namespace.

See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim for more details

Comment: So why in models/todos.js: (https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require/js/models/todo.js) there is use of define( 'backbone' ) ?

Comment: It's unnecssary - if you delete both the underscore and backbone definitions it should still work fine

Comment: I don't really understand the explanation of RequireJS site, so I want to be sure. shim configuration loads the scripts and makes them available inside all the require callbacks without the need to use define)?

Comment: Pretty much. You only need to do it for scripts that are not wrapped in a define() function themselves. It might be worth including them in the definition anyway to be more explicit (althoug, as far as I can tell, it makes no functional difference).

Comment: @matti This is slightly misleading. You still need to have backbone referenced in a define or require dependency array. The shim does not automatically load Backbone into the global namespace. "The shim config only sets up code relationships. To load modules that are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is needed. Setting shim by itself does not trigger code to load." http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim. You are right that it is not needed as a function parameter. Unless you want a local reference. The OP ex. 'views/app' or 'routers/router' loaded Backbone first.